# API endpoints with json-server

Tags: json, node.js, api, server

I'm using json-server to create a test API. I'd like to have make the API endpoint: http://localhost:3000/posts/1/comments

/posts and /posts/1 works fine but I'm not sure why /posts/1/comments doesn't. Am I missing something?

Here is the json

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Post 1",
      "comments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "body": "This is comment 1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Post 2",
      "comments": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are a separate object referenced by `postId`, as follows:

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "json-server",
      "author": "typicode"
    }
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "body": "some comment",
      "postId": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "body": "this is another",
      "postId": 1
    }
  ],
  "profile": {
    "name": "typicode"
  }
}
```

So you can do this :

> localhost/posts/1

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: "json-server",
    author: "typicode"
}
```

> localhost/posts/1/comments

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        body: "some comment",
        postId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        body: "this is another",
        postId: 1
    }
]
```

http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments